# JPA tests hang while obtaining HSQL connection from Maven Command Line

Tags: spring, jpa, datasource, hsqldb, dbunit

Tests work individually within Eclipse (right click, run as Junit), but when I run them from the command line with maven, it stops while trying to obtain a DataSource connection to the HSQL database.

```
LogicalConnectionImpl [DEBUG] Obtaining JDBC connection
```

The oddest part to me is that if I limit the tests being run to 10 (not classes, but individual @Test methods), it will work.  But once that 11th test is run it bombs out.  The test combinations do not matter, so if I have 30 tests, and I choose 11 or more to run, then it will fail. This made me think it is a DataSource connection max issue, but so far no luck with details of that.  I have tried adding heap size just for giggles, but that did not work.

So prior to this hang, I have multiple successful JDBC connection and releases.

Here is my applicationContext-HSQL.xml, which is used for both the in Eclipse and Command Line versions.  I know b/c I have forced each of them to fail by messing with the Class values below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company"/>

    <import resource="classpath*:/application-context-cxf.xml"/>

     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence.xml"  />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"  />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

All of my Test classes utilize Spring 3.2.5, JPA, DBUnit and extend AbstractInMemoryTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext-hsqldb.xml"})
public class AbstractInMemoryTests {

private static final String FLAT_XML_DATASET = "FlatXmlDataSet.xml";

@Autowired
BasicDataSource bds;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(getConnection(), getDataSet());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private IDataSet getDataSet() throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FLAT_XML_DATASET);
    IDataSet dataset = new FlatXmlDataSet(inputStream);
    return dataset;
}

private IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws Exception {
    Connection jdbcConnection = bds.getConnection();
    IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
    return connection;
}
}
```

Any ideas on why I may be hanging on that connection, or an idea of how to troubleshoot?

Thanks,
     Sean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the usual protocol, a good nights sleep helps you think.  I completely over-looked the maxActive setting available for the appContext-hsqldb.xml property for my DataSource

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    ****<property name="maxActive" value="-1"/>****
</bean>
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

Comment: `entityManager.close();` in all methods of my DAOs does the trick here!

Answer (score 1):

if something is hanging you can use "kill -3 {process_number}" on Unix and it gives a thread dump (if not on Unix there is an equivalent on Windows/Mac). That will show where the lock problem is, which may give you an idea what causes it and how to fix it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but so far it appears that killing the process like you suggest does not provide any additional stacktrace information. It still refers me to the SureFire reports, which still do not provide any stack traces.

Comment: nope, you must have got the wrong process number. If you hit the java one of your app it will print a thread dump out, usually in the maven console that it is running from

Answer (score 0):

If the hanging comes after few page access, (maybe 8 which is the default maxTotal), you are not never closing the connection and opening in every request.
Just use `entityManager.close();` after the db queries or check if the a connection already exists before creating a new one.

The accepted answer is setting the maxTotal connections to unlimited. Connections will just keep pilling up.